# Css fail with URL template Spring Boot

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

I have very werid situation. I have a controller with two methods:

```
    @RequestMapping("/gameDetails")
    public String gameDetails1(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("game",gameService.findById(1L));
        return "gameDetails";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/gameDetails/{id}")
    public String gameDetails2(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("game",gameService.findById(1L));
        return "gameDetails";
    }
```

When I open */gameDetails* URL page is OK,

but when I use */gameDetails/1* whole page is messy, like there's no CSS at all. Im using html pages with Thymeleaf. I tried with style tags inside html and with external CSS loaded with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/gameDetails.css" th:href="@{/css/gameDetails.css}" />
```

No success. Do you have any idea what is wrong? How is this even possible?
[image]

Comment: if you inspect the rendered page (or view its source), is the css there? is it pointing to the right dir/file ?

Comment: you can see it right there on the errors, it is trying to find all those files in the  gameDetails/../ folder. if you copy them there it should work, but that is not a real solution. is that the right folder to look for them? it seems that gameDetails/static/ is the right one?
As one works and the other doesn't, one is looking for those css and js in the right dir and the other isn't check that if you have a shared layout/script/css page both are using it. (make a change to it and see that you see it when you inspect both rendered pages)

Comment: You are right. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, try simply changing the realtive path to an absoulte one ... change these href="../static/css/gameDetails.css" to href="/static/css/gameDetails.css" or the correct path from app root